# How to set up "/" path in subdomain route to looking in the different controller than root path in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am try to make my Rails app and admin console under subdomain path.

This is what i have.

```
root 'homepage#index'

  constraints subdomain: 'my' do
    get  '/' => 'admin#index' ,:as => 'admin_dashboard'
  end
```

And i set up my local subdomain host using http://pow.cx/
So everything works fine i can run my app via myapp.dev so smoothly.

But the problem is when i go to

```
my.myapp.dev
```

It should be display `'admin#index'` controller as i need but instead 
it went to `'homepage#index'`

So if i change my route to

```
constraints subdomain: 'my' do
    get  '/dashboard' => 'admin#index' ,:as => 'admin_dashboard'
end
```

Then i go to `'my.myapp.dev/dashboard'` it seems fine it went to `'admin#index'` as i need.

So how can i make

```
constraints subdomain: 'my' do
    get  '/' => 'admin#index' ,:as => 'admin_dashboard'
end
```

To be separated from

```
root 'homepage#index'
```

Or if it can't be how cat i always redirect when user type `my.myapp.dev` to be the url `my.myapp.dev/dashboard`

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `root :to => 'admin#index', :as => 'admin_dashboard'` inside subdomain constraint

Comment: Thanks @VenkatCh i just move root 'homepage#index' under my subdomain route then everything works fine.